# How to add new items in the Flutter grid view builder from the api when the scroll view reaches the middle

Tags: flutter

I am trying to update the list of the models when the scroll view reaches the end, while I was able to do so, I am unable to do it smoothly. I want to load the new images from the API into the List of models whenever the user reaches the middle of the scroll so that the scrolling feels smooth as in the current scenario, there is a second or two of pause when the user hits the end after which the new elements will be added so the user won't know if the new elements are added.
Also, my current approach is putting too much load on the main thread and is crashing the app.

here's the code below:

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/data/data.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/model/categories.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/model/wallpaper_model.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/network/network.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/widgets/branding.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/widgets/list_tile.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/widgets/wallpaper_tile.dart';
var pageIndex=1;
Data data = Data();
List<CategoriesModel> categories;
List<WallpaperModel> wallpapers =[];

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
        if (_controller.position.pixels == 0)
          print('top');
      // you are at top position
      else{
          print('end');
          incrementIndex();
          getWallpapers(pageIndex);
        }

      // you are at bottom position
    }
    });
    categories = data.getCategories();
    getWallpapers(pageIndex);
  }
  ScrollController _controller;

  void incrementIndex(){
    setState(() {
      pageIndex++;
    });
  }

  void getWallpapers(var index) async {
    try {
      Network network = Network();
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = await network.getCuratedWallpapers(
          index, 80);
      jsonData["photos"].forEach((element) {
        WallpaperModel wallpaperModel = WallpaperModel.fromMap(element);
        setState(() {
          wallpapers.add(wallpaperModel);
        });
//      for (var wallpaper in wallpapers){
//        print(wallpaper.src.small);
//      }
      });
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Color(0xff999999), // navigation bar color
    ));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Brand(),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _controller,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                child: ListView.builder(
//                  controller: _controller,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    itemCount: categories.length,
//                  shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CategoriesTile(
                        imageUrl: categories[index].imageUrl,
                        title: categories[index].categoriesName,
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 6.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 6.0,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.6),
                    itemBuilder: (context,index){
//                      if(index==50){
////                        incrementIndex();
//                        getWallpapers(pageIndex+1);
//                      }
                      return WallpaperTile(small: wallpapers[index].src.portrait,);
                    },
                  itemCount: wallpapers.length,
                    ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**wallpaper_model.dart**

```
class WallpaperModel {
  String photographer;
  String photographerUrl;
  int photographerId;
  SrcModel src;
  WallpaperModel(
      {this.photographer, this.photographerUrl, this.photographerId, this.src});
  factory WallpaperModel.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> jsonData){
    return WallpaperModel(
      photographer: jsonData["photographer"],
      photographerId: jsonData["photographer_id"],
      photographerUrl: jsonData["photographer_url"],
      src: SrcModel.fromMap(jsonData["src"])
    );
  }
}

class SrcModel {
  String original;
  String small;
  String portrait;
  SrcModel({this.original, this.small, this.portrait});
  factory SrcModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return SrcModel(
        original: jsonData["original"],
        small: jsonData["small"],
        portrait: jsonData["portrait"]);
  }
}
```

**wallpaper_tile.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WallpaperTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String small;
  WallpaperTile({this.small});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          child:
          Image.network(
        small,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

**network.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
const apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
class Network{
 Future<dynamic> getCuratedWallpapers(var pageNo, var maxWallpapers) async{

   var response = await http.get("https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated/?page=$pageNo&per_page=$maxWallpapers",
       headers: {
     "Authorization":apiKey
   });
   return jsonDecode(response.body);
 }
}
```

the top list view is just for categories and can be ignored.
it's the grid view.builder that has the core functionality

Comment: what you are doing is not a good practice at all, you are rebuilding your widgets very often, you should use Provider or InjeritedWidget to lift the wallpaperList up, that means you will have some object above all of the widgets and you will inject it inside the widget where you want it. after that you will update the injected object's wallpaperList and rebuild the GridView.builder. Thing about Providers and InheritedWidgets is that they don't lose data or change it when their child widgets are updated, unless you are not updating provider's data from some buttonPress function.

Comment: Thanks, I will implement Provider and Change Notifier for the wallpaper list, I hope that fixes the ui thread problem. Could you please also see if I could add a call back when the scroll reaches the middle?

Answer (score 5):

While I couldn't solve the main issue(loading every time the scroll reached the mid of the screen so that the user doesn't have to wait and see the progress bar) but I was able to solve all the other issues besides that.

1. too many images(>3000) was causing the app to crash without a stack trace.
   Solution-> Instead of using a grid view inside a singleChildScrollView, I added it in an Expanded widget which solved that crashing and sluggish scroll behaviour.
2. after a certain number of pages I have started to clear ImageCache because from what I was searching I found that after compressing the images, they can still stay in memory(I still don't know how true that is as that is internal flutter process).
3. I also have used Provider alongside ChangeNotifier instead of setState to avoid extra rebuilding of the widgets.
   Result:- Though the UI isn't super smooth, scrolling is happening seamlessly, images are cleared automatically when they are not in view. There is a second of progress bar after which the next page from the API call is loaded into the list. This is my implementation of lazy loading in a way. I am not calling an async call when another is running by using a boolean.
4. I also added cacheheight and cachewidth to each image to just load compressed image sizes in the grid view and not load full sized images in it.
5. Also, I used the scroll controller to load more elements into the list every time scroll reaches the bottom of the page.
   Here are the main changes.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/data/provider_data.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context)=>ProviderData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        title: 'Wallpaper App',
        home: Home()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/data/data.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/data/provider_data.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/model/categories.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/model/wallpaper_model.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/network/network.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/widgets/branding.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/widgets/list_tile.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/widgets/wallpaper_tile.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pagewise/flutter_pagewise.dart';
Data data = Data();
List<CategoriesModel> categories;
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    categories = data.getCategories();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      _controller = ScrollController();
      _controller.addListener(() {
        if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
          if (_controller.position.pixels == 0)
            print('top');
          // you are at top position
          else{
            print('end');
//          incrementIndex();
            if(Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).pageIndex>5){
              print('image cache: ${imageCache.currentSize}');
              imageCache.clear();
            }
            Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).incrementPage();
            getWallpapers(Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).pageIndex);
          }

          // you are at bottom position
        }
      });
      getWallpapers(Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).pageIndex);
    });

  }
  ScrollController _controller;

  void getWallpapers(var index) async {
    if(!Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).isPerformingRequest){
      Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).togglePerformingRequest();

      try {
        Network network = Network();
        Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = await network.getCuratedWallpapers(
            index, 80);
        jsonData["photos"].forEach((element) {
          WallpaperModel wallpaperModel = WallpaperModel.fromMap(element);
          setState(() {
            Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).addWallpapers(wallpaperModel);
          });
        });
      }
      catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
      Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).togglePerformingRequest();
    }


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return Scaffold(
//      appBar: AppBar(
//        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
//        elevation: 0,
////        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
//        title: Brand(),
//      ),
      body:
//      SingleChildScrollView(
//        controller: _controller,
//        child:
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
//              Container(
//                height: 100,
//                child: ListView.builder(
////                  controller: _controller,
//                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
//                    itemCount: categories.length,
//                  shrinkWrap: true,
//                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
//                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
//                      return CategoriesTile(
//                        imageUrl: categories[index].imageUrl,
//                        title: categories[index].categoriesName,
//                      );
//                    }),
//              ),
//              SizedBox(
//                height: 20,
//              ),
              Expanded(
//                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  controller: _controller,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 6.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 6.0,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.6),
                      addAutomaticKeepAlives: false,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    if(index==(Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).wallpapers!=null?Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).wallpapers.length+0:80)){
                      return _buildProgressIndicator();
                    }
                    else
                    return WallpaperTile(small: Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).wallpapers[index].src.medium,);
                  },
                  itemCount: Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).wallpapers!=null?Provider.of<ProviderData>(context,listen: false).wallpapers.length+1:81,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
//      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
  return new Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: new Center(
      child: new Opacity(
      opacity: 1,
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**wallpaper_model.dart**

```
class WallpaperModel {
  String photographer;
  String photographerUrl;
  int photographerId;
  SrcModel src;
  WallpaperModel(
      {this.photographer, this.photographerUrl, this.photographerId, this.src});
  factory WallpaperModel.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> jsonData){
    return WallpaperModel(
      photographer: jsonData["photographer"],
      photographerId: jsonData["photographer_id"],
      photographerUrl: jsonData["photographer_url"],
      src: SrcModel.fromMap(jsonData["src"])
    );
  }
}

class SrcModel {
  String original;
  String small;
  String portrait;
  String medium;
  SrcModel({this.original, this.small, this.portrait,this.medium});
  factory SrcModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return SrcModel(
        original: jsonData["original"],
        small: jsonData["small"],
        medium: jsonData["medium"],
        portrait: jsonData["portrait"]);
  }
}
```

**network.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
const apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
class Network{
 Future<dynamic> getCuratedWallpapers(var pageNo, var maxWallpapers) async{

   var response = await http.get("https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated/?page=$pageNo&per_page=$maxWallpapers",
       headers: {
     "Authorization":apiKey,
   });
   print(response.statusCode);
//   print(response.body);
   return jsonDecode(response.body);
 }
}
```

**wallpaper_tile.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WallpaperTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String small;
  WallpaperTile({this.small});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          color: Colors.grey
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          child:
          Image.network(
        small,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        cacheHeight: 400,
        cacheWidth: 225,
      )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**provider_data.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/model/wallpaper_model.dart';

class ProviderData extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<WallpaperModel> wallpapers =[];
  bool isPerformingRequest = false;
  var pageIndex=1;

  void togglePerformingRequest(){
    isPerformingRequest = !isPerformingRequest;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void incrementPage(){
    pageIndex++;
    print(pageIndex);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addWallpapers(WallpaperModel wallpaperModel){
    wallpapers.add(wallpaperModel);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: "I added it in an Expanded widget which solved that crashing and sluggish scroll behaviour." this line saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NotificationListener` with `ScrollNotification`. Modify this with your requirements.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int present = 0;
  int perPage = 15;

  final originalItems = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i");
  var items = List<String>();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      items.addAll(originalItems.getRange(present, present + perPage));
      present = present + perPage;
    });
  }

  void loadMore() {
    setState(() {
      if((present + perPage )> originalItems.length) {
        items.addAll(
            originalItems.getRange(present, originalItems.length));
      } else {
        items.addAll(
            originalItems.getRange(present, present + perPage));
      }
      present = present + perPage;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
              scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent / 2) {
            loadMore();
          }
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: (present <= originalItems.length) ? items.length + 1 : items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return (index == items.length ) ?
            Container(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text("Load More"),
                onPressed: () {
                  loadMore();
                },
              ),
            )
                :
            ListTile(
              title: Text('${items[index]}'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Read [more](https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/flutter-loadmore-in-listview-23820612907d).

Comment: I tried it and this condition  (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
              scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent / 2)  is never reached, division by 2 gives different value and even taking the floor is not making it reach that condition. I used treated than eaqual to and the loadmore function that I created is then called continuously after crossing the mid causing the app to crash.

Comment: Can you try something like this? 


          if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels >
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2)

Comment: I tried this too, what happens is that it keeps calling endlessly when I am scrolling down and keeps loading more images continuously. Like every time load more is called I load 80 images from the API. But the height that it is being compared to remains the same for some reason and doesn't change dynamically which causes the app to crash by loading too many images at the same time,

Answer (score 0):

try **SliverGrid** instead of **GridView.builder** in your `home.dart`.

because when you will using `GridView.builder` it will load it's all possible result at once instead of this when you use `SliverGrid` it will load only those data which is currently present in `screen`.

```
SliverGrid(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, int index) {
          final _wallpaper = wallpaper.photos ? [index];
          return Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),), height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .height / 2, child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
            //Wallpaper Preview
          },
            child: Hero(tag: '${_wallpaper?.id}',
              child: ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  imageUrl: _wallpaper!.src!.large!,
                  filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                  progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, progress) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),),),),),);
        }, childCount: wallpaper.photos?.length),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 0.5, crossAxisSpacing: 5.0 mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,),),
```

note: Remove extra that you don't required.